# How to make a button affect a boolean value in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm still learning html and Javascript, so I'm not too good at it. I'm trying to make it so that when I press a button, some text switches from "On" to "Off" and vise versa.

```js
function switch_status() {

  //Setting status to opposite
  if (status = "Turn Appearance Off:") {
    status = "Turn Appearance On:"
  };
  
  if (status = "Turn Appearance On:") {
    status = "Turn Appearance Off:"
  };
  
  //Printing it out
  status_print.innerHTML = status;
}

var status = "Turn Appearance Off:";
var status_print = document.getElementById("status_print");

//calling function
switch_status();
```

```html
<h1 id="status_print">Turn Appearance On:</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="switch_status()">Click Me!</button>
```

As you can see, it's supposed to switch from On to Off when I hit the button. But it doesn't seem to work, help would much be appreciated.

Comment: Hi. A single `=` is _assignment_. [You're looking for either `==` or `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) for those condition statements (`if (status === x`), for example).

Comment: There are a couple of other things: 1) remove the semi-colons from the end of the `if` statements - they're not required. 2) Your condition should be an `if...else` statement. At the moment when you toggle the status when its off you will set it to "on" but then _immediately_ set that status back to "off".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slight adaptation of your code. `el` gets the target element, and is used to get the `status` and also to give it the `newStatus` once you're finished updating the new value.

```js
function switch_status() {
 let el = document.querySelector('#status_print');
 let status = el.innerHTML;
 let newStatus;
  //Setting status to opposite
  if (status === "Turn Appearance Off:") {
    newStatus = "Turn Appearance On:"
  };
  
  if (status === "Turn Appearance On:") {
    newStatus = "Turn Appearance Off:"
  };
  
  //Printing it out
  el.innerHTML = newStatus;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="status_print">Turn Appearance On:</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="switch_status()">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to write two `if` statements and duplicate the messages. Use an actual Boolean to make this much simpler. Also, don't use `.innerHTML` when there's no HTML in the string.

Answer (score 1):

A single `=` means assignment, so when you write:

```
  if (status = "Turn Appearance Off:") {
```

You are actually setting `status` to the value of the string.

Use `===` for strict equality check.

Beyond that, see the comments below for additional things to change.

```js
// Use let to define the scope as block level
// Use const to define a constant
let statusMessage = "";
let status = false;  // Use a Boolean for a binary value
const status_print = document.getElementById("status_print");

// Set up click event handler on the button. Do this in JavaScript
// not with HTML event attributes.
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", switch_status);

function switch_status() {
  // Setting status to opposite
  // Because status is initially false, setting it to the opposite makes it true
  // and vice versa.
  status = !status;

  // Just need to check to see if status === true
  if (status) {
    statusMessage = "Turn Appearance Off:";
  } else {
    statusMessage = "Turn Appearance On:";
  }

  // Printing it out
  // Don't use .innerHTML when there's no HTML in the string
  status_print.textContent = statusMessage;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="status_print">Turn Appearance On:</h1>
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (status = "Turn Appearance Off:")
```

and

```js
if (status = "Turn Appearance On:")
```

are both performing assignment of `status` to a *truthy* string value, meaning the conditions will always be true and each block is always executed in turn.

This means

```js
    status = "Turn Appearance Off:"
```

will always be executed just before the `<h1>` element is updated.

You must use `==` or `===` for comparing equality.

Note that this could be controlled with a single boolean, instead of doing string comparisons. `bool = !bool` is a quick way to flip a boolean value from *true* to *false*, and vice versa.

This can be reduced to:

```js
const display = document.getElementById("status_print");
let isOn = false;

document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click", () => {
  isOn = !isOn;
  
  display.innerHTML = `Turn Appearance ${isOn ? "Off" : "On"}:`;
});
```

```html
<h1 id="status_print">Turn Appearance On:</h1>
<button type="button" id="toggle">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const element = document.getElementById("status_print");
  var is_shown = false;

  function switch_status() {
    //Setting status to opposite
    element.innerHTML = is_shown ? "Turn Appearance On:" : "Turn Appearance Off:"
    is_shown = !is_shown;
  }
```

```html
<h1 id="status_print">Turn Appearance On:</h1>
<button onclick="switch_status()">Click Me!</button>
```

Just for a good practice - you should use a `boolean` to toggle the statement, not set a `string` and check if it is exactly that `string`. Even tho this is also working, it's not really good practice :)

In my code snippet, the `element` and a `boolean` gets declared globally and inside the switch function, the `innerHTML` of the `element` is getting set either to the one or the other `string`, depending on the `boolean`. After that, the `boolean` is toggled.